# How to slow down gif in Photoshop?

Tags: gif

I have a gif file and I want to make it slow motion. I figured I can achieve desired result by duplicating each frame in the gif several times. The problem is there are a lot of frames and duplicating each frame manually is impractical and error prone. Can I automate it somehow? Is there a better way to make gif slow motion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicating frames is the wrong approach. Each frame in a gif has a delay value indicating how long it should be shown before changing to the next one. So if the gif is 10fps then the delay of every frame is 0.1 seconds.

To slow down a gif select all the frames at once, right click and set the delay value to something larger.

[image]